# In MATLAB, is there a simple way to shift the X-axis by a constant offset in bar graphs?

Tags: matlab

I am generating a bar graph of something vs time of day (i.e., 24 hours). Later, my supervisor tells me that in the dataset, the time is offset by 8 hours, so 7 PM needs to become 3 AM, 12 midnight needs to become 8 AM, etc. In other words, the two axes should remain unaffected. Only the plots in the graph need to be made to shift towards the right by 8 hours (i.e., in a circular kind of pattern, where each value is offset by 8). So, is there a simple, single line function or something to do this in MATLAB? Thanks.

This is my code:

```
a=str2num(datestr(n(:,1)/86400,'HH'));  
bar(histc(a,unique(a)))
```

Comment: Can't you just take the time vector `t` and do `t=mod(t+8,24)` if it's in hour units?

Comment: If I do that, I have to redo a long process of previous dependencies. If there is a way to avoid this, that would be great.

Comment: Why do you have to do that? You can do this transformation just before plotting. Or maybe you could elaborate on the difficulty.

Comment: What @AndrasDeak suggests is not actually changing the time, but only the *x-axis*. Thus use something like `xtime = mod(t+8,24)`

Comment: @Adriaan, *then* plot the bar plot with `(xtime,dat)` instead of `(t,dat)`.

Comment: @Adriaan Ok, so, where do I write this line then? I tried doing this: 
`for t=1:24`
`xtime = mod(t+8,24)`
`end`
But it did not work. I used "generate code"; there too I could not any place I could think of where I could put this line.

Comment: @user5346597, maybe you should start adding your code to the question...it's very rare that programming questions can be answered without the code (if you knew what we were talking about, it would have been possible).

Comment: @AndrasDeak Alright, could you please check the question now? I have added my code now. Thank you.

Comment: Yikes, your code is horrifying. Why don't you use auxiliary variables? And maybe you should use the  `N = histc(X,EDGES); bar(EDGES,N,'histc') ` syntax written in `help histc`. Then you could shift `EDGES` with the modulo.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I don't use auxiliary variables because my dataset is already huge (~60 GB). So, I don't want to cause any further memory issues by having more variables, which would all take up some 3-5 GB space.

Comment: @AndrasDeak But anyway, you asked for my code, so you could point out where exactly you want me to write that line you mentioned. And apart from the long lines, there's no issue with my code. So, where do I write that line you wrote about, please?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what you're exactly plotting. There's no issue, apart from that it's hard to understand, but the memory demand might be an acceptable reason (although temporary variables will be defined anyway). With your `bar(histc(...))` syntax you can't shift the x axis, as it's automatically generated by `bar`. If I'm not mistaken, you need `bar(mod(unique(str2num(datestr(n(:,1)/86400,'HH')))+8,24),histc(...))` instead.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Ok, I am looking into it. I'm trying to make it work; it's throwing errors due to my naivete I reckon. I'll let you know if it works. Thanks :)

Comment: Not necessarily your error, I might have misunderstood something. I suggest constructing a smaller example for which you can define temporary variables. If you figure out the syntax for that, you can return to your huge problem.

Comment: Regarding your new code: `bar(unique(a),histc(a,unique(a)))` should plot the same thing. And if so, then `bar(mod(unique(a)+8,24),histc(a,unique(a)))` should be something what you're looking for.

Comment: @AndrasDeak The new code is just an easier to comprehend way of the same thing I had previously, with only the important/relevant lines, and with an intermediate variable. And yeah, your suggestion works. Basically, instead of `a(:,1)=str2num(datestr(nAndroid(:,1)/86400,'HH'))`, I now have `a(:,1)=mod(str2num(datestr(nAndroid(:,1)/86400,'HH'))+8,24)`, and it does the job. Thanks :)

Comment: Sounds like you got your answer but for future reference, [circshift](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html) might be an even more intuitive way to do this.